# Removing Duplicates from a list as well as the elements themselves- Racket, Scheme

Tags: scheme, racket

```
(define (remove-duplicates l)
  (cond ((empty? l)
         '())
        ((member (first l) (rest l))
         (remove-duplicates (rest l)))
        (else
         (cons (first l) (remove-duplicates (rest l))))))
```

This code has this result.

```
> (remove-duplicates (list 1 1 2 2 3 4))
(list 1 2 3 4)
```

Without using filter, I would like the result to be

> (remove-duplicates (list 1 1 2 2 3 4)) gives
>       (list 3 4)

Help would be deeply appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a helper function:

```
(define helper
      (lambda (lst collector dup)
        (cond [(null? lst) collector]
              [(memq (car lst) (cdr lst)) (helper (cdr lst) collector (cons (car lst) dup))]
              [(memq (car lst) dup) (helper (cdr lst) collector dup)]
              [else
               (helper (cdr lst) (cons (car lst) collector) dup)])))
```

Maintain two lst, collector for all unique element, and dup for duplicated elements.

```
(define remove-dup
  (lambda (lst)
    (reverse (helper lst '() '()))))
```

Comment: The function works great, but I'm afraid that it won't work in the larger function. I won't know which elements are going to be the collectors, and which are going to be the duplicates when I execute it.

Comment: What do you mean by "larger function"?

Comment: If you are new to racket/scheme, I suggest you to read "The little schemer".

Comment: I need to use the remove duplicate function in another function. One that removes elements from a list, and I wont know the collector or dup from that function as it could be anything, and I can't be certain whether it will work there.